# How can I print only text from parsed html?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a string that contains some parsed HTML which I'm then printing:

```
print("Setup Complete", *link, sep='\n')
```

This gives

```
   <meta content="https://www.website.com/linktoitem1" itemprop="url"/>
   <meta content="https://www.website.com/linktoitem2" itemprop="url"/>
   etc
```

How can I modify print in order to only display:

```
   https://www.website.com/linktoitem1
   https://www.website.com/linktoitem2
   etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the entire HTML element. If you only want the value of the attribute `content` then you should just print the value, not the entire element.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
   <meta content="https://www.website.com/linktoitem1" itemprop="url"/>
   <meta content="https://www.website.com/linktoitem2" itemprop="url"/>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

link = soup.find_all('meta')

print(*[e['content'] for e in link], sep='\n')
```